# Retrieve records who one field is max

Tags: linq, max

I have some records

```
id     title     date
1      aaa       2005
2      bbb       2003
3      aaa       2007
4      ccc       2005
5      ccc       2009
```

I need to query to retrieve records by Date is max

```
id     title     date
2      bbb       2003
3      aaa       2007
5      ccc       2009
```

Query:

```
select * 
from Table 
where Table.date = (SELECT Max(date) 
                    FROM Table temp 
                    WHERE temp.title = Document.title)
```

I have sql query but need Linq query for this action

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It helps to know what you've already attempted to derive the equivalent in LINQ.  On SO, it's generally looked down upon to ask for how to do something without showing what you've already tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (C#):

```
var results = 
    from x in db.table
    group x by x.title into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            .First();
```

Now for proper paging you'd have to call `Skip` / `Take` on the entire query like this:

```
var results = 
    (from x in db.table
     group x by x.title into g
     select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
             .First())
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: it's working good
but when i use server side paging it's doesn't work properly 

  var results = 
    from x in db.table
    group x by x.title into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            .Skip(0).Take(10).First();

Comment: @HadiRanji See my updated answer for an explanation of properly paging the result set.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` title, order group enumeration by date descending, select first item.  something like this:

```
db.EntityName.GroupBy( en => en.title ).Select( g => g.OrderByDescending( en => en.date ).First() )
```